# find all get parameters and current url

Tags: php, url, get

How would I easily find the current url and all of the GET paramaters in that URL with PHP? I want to track which GET paramaters are being passed to the current url. If somebody could give me the PHP command to do this, then that would be great!
Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
<?php

$filedir = './';

$filename = $_GET['file'];
//security check
if(strpos(realpath($filename), PATH_TO_VALID_MP3s) !== 0) { die('bad path!'); } 
$path = $filedir . $filename;

if (!is_file($path) OR connection_status() != 0)
{
    exit();
}

ob_end_clean();

header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', mktime(date('H')+2, date('i'), date('s'), date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))).' GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '. @filesize($path));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

if ($file = @fopen($path, 'rb'))
{
    while (!feof($file) AND connection_status() == 0)
{
    echo fread($file, 1024 * 8);
}

flush();
}

@fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: `$passedGetParams = $_GET;` ?

Comment: BTW possible duplicate of many `how to get current page url in php` questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a global variable present that contains all the GET variables.

```
$_GET
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

An alternative is the `$_REQUEST` global.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Comment: so whould i just do echo $_GET?

Comment: I don't know what you wan't to do with them. You should read the PHP manual on how to use them for the solution you're after.

Comment: I just want to see the paramaters and send them in an email

Comment: In that case use `$get = print_r($_GET, true)`. It will return the textual array representation of `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) arrays are your friends ;)

Comment: Further note, that `$_SERVER` will also contain the unparsed query string. This might be interesting if you are interested in the order of GET params

Comment: Yes, i know, but people visit download.php?file=filename.mp3 and that would download filename.mp3.... this is in a directory with only nonvulnerable mp3 files, but i just want to make sure they dont find a way to download root directory files. That is why i ask

Comment: `if(strpos(realpath($filename), PATH_TO_VALID_MP3s) !== 0) { die('bad path!'); }`

Comment: Ohhh that looks awesome!!!! CAnt wait to see what it does, one minute please!

Comment: That should go at the very top of the page, correct?

Comment: OOPS! One problem with that @hek2mgl, some of the files are WAV and MP3 and other audio, is there like one that will be for all audio instead of just MP3?